# android how to use multiple switch widgets

Tags: android, togglebutton

According to [references](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html), ToggleButtons and Switches are supposed to be used with an OnCheckedChangeListener or with a function like onToggleClicked(View view).

However, both ways return void and the inner if statement, which is either `if (on)` or `if (checked)`, or `if (isChecked)`, doesn't let me to set a usable variable. The same applies for radio buttons.

I have an app where I'd like to calculate daily energy requirements of intensive care patients. I need to use multiple switches; and all these selectors jointly affect a calculation. An example formula is:

1784 + (5 * weight) - (11 * age) + (244 if male) + (239 if trauma patient) + (804 if burn patient)

Below is an example including a single switch. Ididn't include my solution for all the switches/parameters, since that's too many code clutter:

```
public double calculateBMI(View view) {
  EditText getHeight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.height);  // find the widget
  String height_as_string = getHeight.getText().toString();  // get the string
  int height = Integer.parseInt(height_as_string);           // convert to integer    

  Switch gender = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.gender);         // find the switch

  double heightConvertedToInch = height / 2.54;  // convert height to inch
  // calculate ideal body weight        
  if(gender.isChecked()){                        // gender is male
    double idealBodyWeight = 106 + ( 6 * heightConvertedToInch );
    return idealBodyWeight;
  } else {                                       // gender is female
    double idealBodyWeight = 100 + ( 5 * heightConvertedToInch );
    return idealBodyWeight;
  }
}
```

Comment: why can't you set global boolean fields from inside the onCheckedChanged() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to references, ToggleButtons and Switches are supposed to be used with an OnCheckedChangeListener or with a function like onToggleClicked(View view).

Those are event listeners, if you need to take immediate action based upon the change of the state of the compound button, such as enabling/disabling other widgets. They are not needed otherwise.

> What is the proper way to handle this situation?

Call `isChecked()` on each `CompoundButton` (whether `ToggleButton` or `Switch` or `CheckBox` or whatever), and use that information to "affect a calculation".

Comment: Sorry for the late return. isChecked() worked when the calculation is going to be displayed in the next activity. But what should I do to display the result in the same activity, in a TextView for example? Should I use nested if conditions?

Comment: @barerd: I have no idea what you are referring to. `isChecked()` is a method on a Java class named `CompoundButton`. You can only call it when you have access to the `CompoundButton`. That will be in the activity that displays the `CompoundButton`. What you do with the `boolean` value you get from `isChecked()` is up to you. But you can certainly affect the UI of the activity that holds the `CompoundButton`. If you want to find out, in real time, when the user toggles it on/off, use an `OnCheckedChangeListener` to find out about the state change.

Comment: :To clarify, I have four switches. For example, one of them is gender. I'd like to see the result change/updated (on the same UI of the activity that holds the CompoundButton) whenever I toggle the switches (any and all of them).Since the formula contains all of the switches as parameters, the only solution I found is to use nested if statements. That's because the OnCheckedChangeListener forces me to use an if statement, and I cannot access the local variables inside the if statement from outside that method. I asked about this condition.

Comment: @barerd: I have no idea what "the formula" is. I have no way of knowing if "nested if statements" is the appropriate approach for implementing "the formula". I have no way of knowing if your "forces me tio use an if statement" assertion is accurate. I have tried to provide what information I can, given your cryptic question.

Comment: I see the point. I added one of the formulas and my solution for a single switch. I'd be glad if you could very mind to check it.

Comment: @barerd: I'd put the `findViewById()` calls in `onCreate()`, after the `setContentView()` call, so you only have to look them up once. Put the widgets in data members of your activity class, and then you can just reference them from your `calculateBMI()` method. I'd also strongly recommend making your magic numbers be `static final int` or `static final float` values as constants, so others reading your code (including future versions of you) know what the magic numbers refer to. Otherwise, I don't see any particular problem with what you have here.